# Find all numbers in a string in a listbox and add them up

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a listbox in winforms and it will contain a bunch of text and I want to find all the decminal numbers and add them up. All the decimal numbers will be after a hyphen. I will create an example of the listbox below.

---

```
Listbox

Sandwich - 5.00 
no onions

bbq sauce - 1.00

Can - 1.00
coke
```

---

```
var sum = OrderListBox.Items
        .OfType<string>()
        .Select(s => Convert.ToDecimal(s.Split(new string[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]))
        .Sum();
```

I have this code but it errors whenever the listbox has a blank line or a line of text without a hyphen followed by a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regex ( `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` ) with the following:

```
string firstPattern = "-\\s*[0-9.]+";
string detailPattern = "[0-9.]+";
Regex firstRegex = new Regex(firstPattern);
Regex detailRegex = new Regex(detailPattern);
double sum = 0;
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
     string match = firstRegex.Match(item).Value;
     if (match != String.Empty)
     {
          double toAdd = 0;
          string num = detailRegex.Match(match).Value;
          Double.TryParse(num, out toAdd);
          sum += toAdd;
     }
}
```

This finds the strings with the hyphen followed by a number and then within that string just finds the number part of it.  Then parse it to a double and add it to your sum variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var stringList = new List<string> {
            "Sandwich - 5.00 ",
            "no onions",
            "bbq sauce - 1.00",
            "Can - 1.00",
            "coke"
        };
    
        decimal total = 0.00m;
        foreach( var s in stringList )
        {
            decimal numericValue = 0.00m;
            var dashLocation = s.IndexOf('-');
            if (dashLocation > -1)
            {
                var stringValue = s.Substring(dashLocation+1);
                if (Decimal.TryParse(stringValue, out numericValue))
                {
                    total += numericValue;
                }
            }
        }   
        Console.WriteLine("Total {0}", total ); 
    }
}
```